# How does the if statement know from kb.next that there's 2 options to be chose from?

Tags: java

The question truly is how does my if statement choose from 2 different options? Like if I type "Y" it should go through even though the other choice is "Yes"?

```
System.out.println("What kind of character would you like?");
        System.out.println("Theres:");
        System.out.println("1. Fighter");
        System.out.println("2. Archer");
        System.out.println("3. Magician");
        System.out.println("Please Choose Now.");
        
        int playerSelection = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        if(playerSelection == 1){
            System.out.println(j001 + ". Would you like to confirm?");
            String playerConfirm = kb.next();
            if(playerConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes" | "Y")){
               System.out.println("Good choice, continuing to game.");
               playerType = true;
            }
            else if(playerConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("No" | "N")){
                System.out.println("Re-showing characters.");
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

It gives me an error saying my operator isn't working/valid.

Comment: @Darkman `kb` would seem to be short for "keyboard." Neither `||` nor `|` will work here; it isn't the ***Strings*** that OP needs to be OR-ing.

Comment: @DavidConrad Uh, my mistake there. It shows how stupid I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present you have:

```
playerConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes" | "Y")
```

This is saying "calculate the value of the expression `"Yes" | "Y"` and pass the resulting `String` to `equalsIgnoreCase`.

But applying the bitwise OR operator (or the logical OR operator) to two Strings doesn't work.

You will need to check each case separately, i.e:

```
playerConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || playerConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
```